# pyodbc doesn't correctly deal with unicode data

Tags: python, mysql, encoding, utf-8, pyodbc

I did successfully connected MySQL database with pyodbc, and it works well with ascii encoded data, but when I print data encoded with unicode(utf8), it raised error:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-8: ordinal not in range(128)
```

So I checked the string in the row:

```
>>>row[3]
'\xe7\xae\xa1\xe7\x90\u2020\xe5\u2018\u02dc'
```

I found [instructions about unicode in pyodbc github wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Unicode)

> These databases tend to use a single encoding and do not differentiate
>   between "SQL_CHAR" and "SQL_WCHAR". Therefore you must configure them
>   to encode Unicode data as UTF-8 and to decode both C buffer types
>   using UTF-8.
>
> ```
> # Python 3.x
> cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
> cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
> cnxn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
> ```
>
> If you are using MySQL, you can add the character set to the
>   connection string, but I'm not sure if this is necessary.
>
> ```
> # MySQL
> cstring = 'DSN=mydsn;CharSet=utf8'
> cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cstring)
> ```

I did as above, but nothing different.
Flowing is my code

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import pyodbc
import configparser
class ServerDBDAO():
    def __init__(self):
        ''' Establish connection to SQL'''
        # Read config
        self.cf = configparser.ConfigParser()
        self.cf.read("./Config/server.ini")
        driver = self.cf.get('Database', 'Driver')
        server = self.cf.get('Database', 'Server')
        database = self.cf.get('Database', 'Database')
        uid = self.cf.get('Database', 'UID')
        pwd = self.cf.get('Database', 'PWD')

        # Connect database
        connString = 'DRIVER=%s;SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;UID=%s;PWD=%s;CharSet=utf8'%(driver, server, database, uid, pwd)
        '''Successfully connected database with this
        self.conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/odbc/libmyodbc.so;SERVER=localhost;DATABASE=xxx;UID=root;PWD=xxxxxx'))
        '''
        self.conn = pyodbc.connect(connString,unicode_results=True)
        self.conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
        self.conn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
        self.conn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
        self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

    def __del__(self):
        self.conn.commit()
        self.conn.close()
```

test code:

```
from ServerDBDAO import ServerDBDAO
dbdao = ServerDBDAO()
row_employee = cursor.execute('select id, name, email from Employee;').fetchone()
print(row_employee.name)
```

Comment: What version of MySQL Connector/ODBC are you trying to use? How did you install it? Your question mentions `libmyodbc.so`, but current versions of the MySQL ODBC driver actually come in two flavours: `libmyodbc5a.so` for "ANSI" and `libmyodbc5w.so` for Unicode. Are you sure that the version you are using supports Unicode?

Comment: Don't do any encoding/decoding in your code.  Just let it all be UTF-8.

Comment: @GordThompson I simply installed odbc with 'apt-get install libmyodbc', it only provides this libmyodbc.so file. I will try libmyodbc5w.so and see how it works. Appreciate your help very much!

Comment: @RickJames I didn't use the encoding an decoding stuff in the beginning, it didn't work, so i added the code according to pyodbc wiki, it didn't work ether way. Thanks for replying anyway.

Comment: @GordThompson I installed MySQL Connector/ODBC 5.3 from mysql official site[link](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/). Tried libmyodbc5w.so, met another error of connection [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40939408/connecting-to-mysql-using-pydobc), and solved it with a soft link, but it raised the UnicodeEncodeError like before.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of pyodbc (currently 4.0.14)?

Comment: @GordThompson I checked just now, it is 4.0.14, installed it with pip3 quite recently.

Comment: When it comes to character encoding, MySQL has quite a few "moving parts", and that can make it difficult to troubleshoot remotely. For what it's worth, I just did a quick test on Xubuntu 16.04/x64 with the latest versions of pyodbc (4.0.14) and MySQL Connector/ODBC (5.3.7, Unicode) and it worked fine. Have a look at the test code [here](http://pastebin.com/KZsLNHuS) and see if anything looks significantly different from your setup.

Comment: `'\xe7\xae\xa1\xe7\x90\u2020\xe5\u2018\u02dc'` is gibberish -- it does not correspond to any encoding.  It is not utf8, nor unicode, nor ascii, nor 30 other encodings I checked.  What should it say?  Is that the raw data?  Or has it been transformed in any way?

Comment: @GordThompson OK, I will setup a new test environment. I was testing on a VPS I have been using for a while, might have messed up something. You ensured me there is nothing wrong with pyodbc or odbc connector, that helps a lot, I even thought about giving up pyodbc for a second. Will Inform you of any progress, thanks a lot !

Comment: @RickJames Yes, that is where it is weired, everything works fine with ascii encoded data. When I 'print(row.email)' everything's fine.

Comment: @GordThompson It worked on my laptop debian system!!! exatly same code, same connector/odbc, same setup method! Still can't figure out what went wrong, but it just worked! You did great help, thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @RickJames It worked when I setup a new environment! There's nothing wrong with the code or connector/odbc or pyodbc. Can't figure out why, but it just worked! Appreciate you help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I faced the same issue. In addition to using these:

```
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_CHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WCHAR, encoding='utf-8')
cnxn.setencoding(encoding='utf-8')
```

Adding this resolved the issue for me:

```
cnxn.setdecoding(pyodbc.SQL_WMETADATA, encoding='utf-32le')
```

Comment: That's interesting... I'v heard MySQL 'utf-8' encoding is not a real utf-8 standard encoding, it is a MySQL-invented encoding. Instead, 'utf8mb4' in MySQL is the real utf-8. Not sure if that is the root cause, I have abandoned the environment long ago, and probably not able to reproduce it.